# Why don't my maps appear?

Tags: garrys-mod

I downloaded a Pokémon castle map in Garry's mod, but, when I went to "START A NEW GAME" the map was not there. I have other maps which don't work either.

How do I get the maps to appear when I start a game?

Comment: Have you checked under 'Other'? What is the name of the map? GMod tries to auto-categorize maps based on their starting prefixes (`gm_` corresponds to Sandbox, `cp_` corresponds to a Team Fortress 2 map, `d1_` corresponds to HL2 maps, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If your map files are of type .bsp and they are in the folder 'common/Garry's Mod/garrysmod/Maps' they should be detected in one of the map categories inside your 'Start New Game' map selection.